# How do I request a single record using AWS DynamoDB? Code samples are not working

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs, dynamodb-queries

I have taken the code sample down the the very basics and I am still unable to retrieve a single record by the key.  Here is my basic example with nodejs (creds not included in this snippet):

```
var dynamodbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName: 'newsarticles',
    Key: { id: '068d1110-cd0c-11e8-a4d4-57cb772554a4' }
};

//log full dynamodb request object
console.log("request params: ", JSON.stringify(params));

//make dynamodb request
dynamodbClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error: " + err)
    } else {
        console.log(data.Item);
    }
});
```

running this code above example gives me the following error:

**ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema**

my dataset gets inserted easily and the records in the system look like this example:

```
{
  "added": 1539231216801,
  "description": "A number of ethics complaints filed against Supreme Court Justice Brett Kavanaugh have yet to be resolved and will be transferred to a new jurisdiction, Chief Justice John Roberts wrote in a letter Wednesday. ",
  "edited": 1539231216402,
  "id": "068d1110-cd0c-11e8-a4d4-57cb772554a4",
  "largeImageUrl": "https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2018/10/09/105496148-1539094642099gettyimages-1047769784.1910x1000.jpeg",
  "newstitle": "Ethics complaints against Brett Kavanaugh have not been resolved yet",
  "newsurl": "https://www.cnbc.com/2018/10/10/ethics-complaints-against-brett-kavanaugh-have-not-been-resolved-yet.html",
  "posted": 1539231216402,
  "scrapeid": "05c3a690-cd0c-11e8-a4d4-57cb772554a4",
  "scrapes": [
    "05c3a690-cd0c-11e8-a4d4-57cb772554a4"
  ],
  "source": "www.cnbc.com",
  "type": "rate"
}
```

The table is defined like this:

Table name: **newsarticles**

Primary partition key:  **id (String)**

Primary sort key:   **added (Number)**

The error message doesn't really tell me what the issue is.  Could anyone see what is wrong in my request?  Is there another way to diagnose what may be missing or incorrect?  Thanks in advance, sorry about the NOOB question but I am just starting with AWS DynamoDB for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not including the full primary key, you need to specify the sort key also,`added` in this case

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'newsarticles',
    Key: {
      id: '068d1110-cd0c-11e8-a4d4-57cb772554a4',
      added: aNumberHere
    }
};
```

Alternately if you are trying to get all the record with a specific id you need to use a query.

Comment: So I have to use both the Primary and Sort Keys if I include the Sort key? hmm, I had thought that was just used in order to make faster > or < a "provided date" for the queries (like an additional free "order by" indexer).  The way you have to construct your data for dynamodb is confusing.  For everyone else reading this question his answer above was indeed the issue.  Marking it. Thanks @cementblocks!

Comment: this is what i tested and worked:

`var params = {
    TableName: 'newsarticles',
    Key: { 
        id: '068d1110-cd0c-11e8-a4d4-57cb772554a4',
        added: 1539231216801
    }
};`

Comment: hey @cementmixer, why does this simple request on an indexed Primary Key take 250ms? that seems crazy long.  My DB has less than 100 rows.

Comment: Probably network latency and connection overhead. You can get a faster response if you reuse connections. Also the latency for gets is not related to the number of rows in the table. I have tables with 500m+ rows and latency is not increased.